# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar la información de la consulta de la url en la web?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, binance

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const aplicacion = document.querySelector('.container')


var burl = "https://api.binance.com";

var query = '/api/v1/ticker/24hr';
    
query += '?symbol=BTCUSDT';

var url = burl + query;

   
fetch(url)
.then(res =>res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Comment: `.innerHTML`, por ejemplo `document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea básica es establecer *lugares* dentro de tu página Web para mostrar la información.

En el ejemplo a continuación, mostraré la respuesta obtenida, como tal, pero también un par de los valores ya interpretados.

Para lograr esto, me valgo de `getElementById`, para obtener referencias a los elementos del DOM, y luego asigno valores a sus propiedades, en concreto, a `innerHTML` en el caso del DIV, y a `value` en el caso de los INPUTs.

Siguiendo esta técnica, puedes dejar valores en cualquier tipo de elemento que hayas previsto, dentro de tu diseño, siempre que tengas forma de localizarlo desde tu script. Lo más rápido y sencillo es asignarle a cada uno un `id` único y buscarlos con `getElementById`, pero no es lo único, hay ocasiones en que debes tirar de otros métodos, uno bastante común también es asignarles a todos una misma clase CSS y luego ubicarlos por dicha clase, o también por el tipo de elemento, solo por mencionar algunas.

Para ello puedes valerte de funciones como `querySelector()` o `querySelectorAll()` de la interfaz `document`.

Creo que el código se auto-explica, si tienes dudas o comentarios, dejalos abajo.

```html
<h1>Información cruda:</h1>
<div id="infocruda"></div>
<h1>Información estructurada:</h1>
<div id="infoestructurada">
  <label for="symbol">Símbolo: </label>
  <input id="symbol" value="saber">
  <label for="princeChange">Cambio de precio: </label>
  <input id="priceChange" value="saber">
<div>

<script>

let burl = "https://api.binance.com";
let query = '/api/v1/ticker/24hr';
query += '?symbol=BTCUSDT';
let url = burl + query;

let infocruda = document.getElementById('infocruda');
let isymbol = document.getElementById('symbol');
let ipriceChange = document.getElementById('priceChange');
   
fetch(url)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  infocruda.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data);
  isymbol.value = data.symbol;
  ipriceChange.value = data.priceChange;
})
</script>
```

El ejemplo puedes probarlo aquí mismo en esta pestaña del navegador, haciendo clic en el botón *"Ejecutar"*.

Comment: @JMA, es un gusto ser de ayuda, utiliza la sintaxis arroba-usuario (como hago yo en este comentario) para mencionar a alguien, de otra forma no recibirá una notificación de tu comentario. En este caso, yo la recibí porque comentaste en mi respuesta. Por otro lado, si la respuesta resuelve tu problema, [aceptala y considera votar a favor de ella](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Si no sabes como hacerlo, te invito a re-hacer el [tour]. Un saludo.